# Using "for" loops in R package and error message "Error in `[.data.frame`(, c("date", i)) : undefined columns selected"

Tags: r, for-loop

Question relates to using "for" loops in R package and handling error message"undefined columns.

Sample date frame consists of 4 rows and 10 columns. Libraries used magritter and dplyr.

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

date <- c ("2020-12-31", "2021-01-29", "2021-02-26", "2021-03-31")
v_1 <- c(66.39, 70.46, 69.37, 67.73) 
v_2 <- c(14.16, 12.31, 13.07, 12.85) 
v_3 <- c(14.37, 13.02, 13.09, 14.88) 
v_4 <- c(0.94, 0.83, 0.74, 0.79) 
v_5 <- c(0.42, 0.37, 0.33, 0.29) 
v_6 <- c(1.51, 1.30, 1.14, 1.12) 
v_7 <- c(1.84, 1.37, 1.91, 1.99) 
v_8 <- c(0.16, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14)
v_9 <- c(0.21, 0.20, 0.21, 0.21) 

raw.data <- data.frame(date, v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4, v_5, v_6, v_7, v_8, v_9)
```

The variables v_1 through v_9 are each assigned a priority, namely "High", "Medium" or "Low"

```
Priority <- c("High", "Medium", "Low")

  High <- c("v_4", "v_7")
  Medium <- c("v_2", "v_3", "v_9")
  Low <- c("v_1", "v_5", "v_6", "v_8")
```

Required output in tidy/long format to contain 12 rows and 3 columns.

12 Rows: date variable that is repeated thrice.

3 columns: date, Priority and Priority Total. (Priority Total is the row wise sum of the variables falling under each priority category)

```
      date        Priority    Priority_Total
  1  2020-12-31     High           2.78
  2  2021-01-29     High           2.20
  3  2021-02-26     High           2.65
  4  2021-03-31     High           2.78
  5  2020-12-31   Medium          28.74
  6  2021-01-29   Medium          25.53
  7  2021-02-26   Medium          26.37
  8  2021-03-31   Medium          27.94
  9  2020-12-31      Low          68.48
  10 2021-01-29      Low          72.27
  11 2021-02-26      Low          70.98
  12 2021-03-31      Low          69.28
```

Required output obtained successfully using the paste and copy method.

Note that "tmp" is a temporary work space.

```
  pc_output <- NULL # Required output initialized
  

   # High Priority
    
    tmp <- raw.data[,c("date",High)] %>% # Selecting date and high priority variables. 
    
    mutate(Priority_Total=select(.,-1) %>% # Generating a priority total by summing across the rows.
            apply(1,sum,na.rm=TRUE)) %>% 
            mutate(Priority="High") # Generating a priority category column containing value "High"
  
    tmp <- tmp[,c("date","Priority","Priority_Total")] # Retaining the 3 required columns
    
    pc_output <- rbind(pc_output,tmp) # Merging the derived result with pc_output 
  
# The same procedure is used for medium and low priority variables
  
    # Medium Priority 
    tmp <- raw.data[,c("date",Medium)] %>% # Selecting date and medium priority variables. 
      
      mutate(Priority_Total=select(.,-1) %>% # Generating a priority total by summing across the rows.
               apply(1,sum,na.rm=TRUE)) %>% 
      mutate(Priority="Medium") # Generating a priority category column containing value "Medium"
    
    tmp <- tmp[,c("date","Priority","Priority_Total")] # Retaining the 3 required columns
    
    pc_output <- rbind(pc_output,tmp) # Merging the derived result with pc_output 
    

    # Low Priority 
    tmp <- raw.data[,c("date",Low)] %>% # Selecting date and low priority variables. 
      mutate(Priority_Total=select(.,-1) %>% # Generating a priority total by summing across the rows.
      apply(1,sum,na.rm=TRUE)) %>% 
      mutate(Priority="Low") # Generating a priority category column containing value "Low"
    
    tmp <- tmp[,c("date","Priority","Priority_Total")] # Retaining the 3 required columns
    
    pc_output <- rbind(pc_output,tmp) # Merging the derived result with pc_output
    
    rm(tmp) # Clearing the temporary work space

    print(pc_output)
```

The "paste and copy" method was run to ensure that all the columns were properly defined.

However when the "for" loop was used, the "undefined columns" problem was encountered.

```
    output <- NULL

    for (i in (Priority)){
      tmp <- raw.data[,c("date",i)] %>% 
      mutate(Priority_Total=select(.,-1) %>%
          apply(1,sum,na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
          mutate(Priority=i)

      tmp <- tmp[,c("date","Priority","Priority_Total")]

  output <- rbind(output,tmp)
  }
```

Message : "Error in `[.data.frame`(raw.data, , c("date", i)) : undefined columns selected"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loops are rarely the optimal solution to such data transformation problems, as vectorized alternatives exist that are both faster and likely easier to read. As for the error you encountered - `c("date", 1)` evaluates to a vector of length 2. That is, R tries to evaluate `raw.data[, c("date", "1")]`, while `raw.data[, c("date", paste0("v_", i))]` might be what you intended to do. Here is `dplyr` alternative without the for-loop:

```
raw.data %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("v"),
               names_to = "Priority") %>%
  mutate(Priority = case_when(
    Priority %in% c("v_4", "v_7") ~ "High",
    Priority %in% c("v_2", "v_3", "v_9") ~ "Medium",
    Priority %in% c("v_1", "v_5", "v_6", "v_8") ~ "Low",
    TRUE ~ NA_character_
  )) %>%
  group_by(date, Priority) %>%
  summarise(Priority_Total = sum(value, na.rm = T), .groups = "drop") %>%
  arrange(factor(Priority, levels = c("High", "Medium", "Low")))

# A tibble: 12 x 3
   date       Priority Priority_Total
   <chr>      <chr>             <dbl>
 1 2020-12-31 High               2.78
 2 2021-01-29 High               2.2 
 3 2021-02-26 High               2.65
 4 2021-03-31 High               2.78
 5 2020-12-31 Medium            28.7 
 6 2021-01-29 Medium            25.5 
 7 2021-02-26 Medium            26.4 
 8 2021-03-31 Medium            27.9 
 9 2020-12-31 Low               68.5 
10 2021-01-29 Low               72.3 
11 2021-02-26 Low               71.0 
12 2021-03-31 Low               69.3
```

Comment: Donald, your solution works perfectly. Thank you.